What happened to Leland?
In the final episode of the last season of Evil, Leland finally decides to try to

kill Kristen once and for all.

Kristen subdues him, after which various people are seen dragging Leland in a burlap sack, after which he appears to be shoved into a cabinet that almost looks too small to contain him, after which the series skips to Kristen living in Vatican City.
What exactly was Leland's final fate? Held captive by Sister Andrea? (But why would anyone see this as a foolproof solution?) Temporarily put there before being shipped off to the Entity? Sealed in some kind of supernatural prison (but Kristen and Ben seemed to accept it very readily)?

Leland is being locked up in the demon box at the Sacred Trinity Silent Monastery. This box appeared in “S Is For Silence” S2E7. It is actually the reason why it is a silent monastery, because if someone talks, a demon will get out of the box and cannot be captured again.

Welcome to Movies.SE! Can you clarify when and how this is stated in the series, for OP's benefit?

This box appeared in “S Is For Silence” S2E7, it is actually is the reason why it is silent monastery, because if someone talks, daemon will get out of the box and couldnt be captured again.

So, basically, from David's perspective, it will hold Leland because he is a demon, whereas from Ben and perhaps Kristen's perspective, he's going to be held prisoner by a whole order of nuns in a box that he probably believes he cannot escape from, so he is unlikely to get out.
